How do I redirect all the routes from one module to another keeping the path segements and query params and states?
Suppose the following route configs:
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "home",
    canMatch: [platformGuard],
    canActivate: [authenticationGuard],
    resolve: {userConfig: userConfigResolver},
    loadChildren: () => import("@netway/home/home.module").then(value => value.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: "pwa",
    canMatch: [platformGuard],
    canActivate: [authenticationGuard],
    resolve: {userConfig: userConfigResolver},
    loadChildren: () => import("@netway/pwa/pwa.module").then(value => value.PwaModule),
  },
];

export const PwaRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    redirectTo: "tab/home"
  },
  {
    path: "tab",
    canActivate: [authenticationGuard],
    loadComponent: () => import("@netway/pwa/pwa.component").then((x) => x.PwaComponent),
    children: [
      {
        path: "home",
        loadComponent: () => import("@netway/pwa/tab/home/pwa-home.component").then((x) => x.PwaHomeComponent),
        canActivateChild: [authenticationChildGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: "",
            pathMatch: "full",
            title: "pwa.tab.home",
            loadComponent: () => import("@netway/pwa/tab/home/home-main/pwa-home-main.component").then((x) => x.PwaHomeMainComponent)
          },
          {
            path: "page",
            loadComponent: () => import("@netway/pwa/tab/home/home-children/pwa-home-children.component").then((x) => x.PwaHomeChildrenComponent),
            children: [
              {
                path: "userCustomHome",
                title: "menu.dashboard",
                component: UserCustomHomeComponent,
                data: {layoutName: LayoutName.HOME}
              },
              {
                path: "process",
                loadChildren: () => import("../process/process.module").then(p => p.ProcessModule)
              },
              {
                path: "widgetProcess",
                loadChildren: () => import("../widget-process/widget-process.module").then(p => p.WidgetProcessModule)
              },
              {
                path: "depositList",
                title: "depositList.title",
                loadChildren: () => import("../deposit-list/deposit-list.module").then(d => d.DepositListModule)
              },
              {
                path: "billStatements",
                title: "depositList.actionBar.billAccount",
                component: DepositBillStatementComponent
              },
              {
                path: "loan",
                title: "loan.menu.title",
                loadChildren: () => import("../loan/loan.module").then(l => l.LoanModule)
              },

              {
                path: "cardlessCash",
                title: "cardless.page.title",
                loadChildren: () => import("../cardless-cash/cardless-cash.module").then(c => c.CardlessCashModule)
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
];

The children hirearchy in "home/page/" are exactly the same as the ones in "pwa/tab/home/page/".
In my code I navigated to the pathes somehow like this: this.router.navigate("home/page/[path to the desired child]). As you see there's no sign of PWA path because it has been added to the source code recently.
The role of platformGuard is to redirect all the pathes from home to pwa when the device is a supported gadget.
Now, my question is how to route to PWA routes without modifing dozens of this.router.navigate() absolute routing calls in my source code?
Currently, I introduced a new service and use it whenever I have to route in an absolute way:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PathService {
  private readonly platformService = inject(PlatformService);

  /**
   * @desc Use this method when you have to navigate from one module to another one.
   *
   * IMPORTANT: Don't use this method when you can solve your issue using relative routes.
   * @param partialPath The raw absolute path which needs to be modified based on the current mode (NW or PWA).
   * @return The modified absolute path based on the current mode as an array of strings
   */
  getAbsolute(...partialPath: ReadonlyArray<string>): Array<any> {
    partialPath = this.format(...partialPath);
    const pathPrefix = this.platformService.isPwaMode() ? ["pwa", "tab"] : [];
    return [...pathPrefix, ...partialPath];
  }

  /**
   *  @desc Removes all the route slashes and flattens the path segments to a single array
   */
  private format(...partialPath: Array<string>) {
    return partialPath.flatMap(
      pathSegment => pathSegment.split("/").filter(segment => segment !== "")
    );
  }
}

One sample usage:
      this.router.navigate(
        this.pathService.getAbsolute("home", "page", "kartablRegister"),
        {
          queryParams: { kartablId: kartablId, asEditing: true }
        }
      );

The drawback of this solution is that I need to modify all thos this.router.navigate() calls.
How can I achieve the same result without the need to modify my existing this.router.navigate() calls?

I guess one way you could achieve this is by adding a canActivateChild on the non PWA routes that will redirect to the matching PWA route if the app is running on a supported platform :
app.routes.ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "home",
    canMatch: [platformGuard],
    canActivate: [authenticationGuard],
    // Here is the new CanActivate
    canActivateChild: [platformRedirectGuard],
    resolve: {userConfig: userConfigResolver},
    loadChildren: () => import("@netway/home/home.module").then(value => value.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: "pwa",
    canMatch: [platformGuard],
    canActivate: [authenticationGuard],
    resolve: {userConfig: userConfigResolver},
    loadChildren: () => import("@netway/pwa/pwa.module").then(value => value.PwaModule),
  },
];

The guard that will now run on every child routes of "home" can detect if the device is compatible as your platformGuard is doing, on compatible device, it will rewrite the path to redirect the user to the appropriate route on the PWA version of your app.
platform-redirect.guard.ts
export const platformRedirectGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  // Use your service to detect compatible devices :
  const platformService = inject(PlatformService);
  if (platformService.compatiblePlatform()) {
    // Redirect to the matching pwa route
    return inject(Router).createUrlTree(
      ['/pwa/tab' + state.url], 
      { queryParams: route.queryParams }
    );
  }
  return true;
};

But this also means that the platformRedirect function will run on ever router.navigate that poins on the root "home" path.

I think this way, we lose the navigation state and query params, don't we?

That is most certainly true, I must admit I should have dig deeper with my answer, I still think It could be doable this way, I'll check and edit my answer if I find a way.

So after some testings, it's easy enough to pass the current queryParams to the new route, the Angular Params (/route/:id) are preserved through the state.url and as the navigation didn't complete due to the canActivate the navigation state is clean.
You should try and see if it works for your use case.
